# Pandas and ValueError: time data '0' does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I can not figure out why I get the error "ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' (match)" (or ..'%d.%m.%Y'). So, I have a test dataframe:

```
          Date      DateCP   Time    kWh                DT
0   01.11.2022  01.11.2022  01:00  0.693  01.11.2022 01:00
1   01.11.2022  01.11.2022  02:00  0.675  01.11.2022 02:00
2   01.11.2022  01.11.2022  03:00  1.044  01.11.2022 03:00
```

to be absolutely sure (following suggestions here) I run on both DateCP and DT:

```
df['DateCP'] = df['DateCP'].apply(unidecode) 
df['DT'] = df['DT'].apply(unidecode)
```

but issuing

```
df['DateCP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCP'], format='%d.%m.%Y') 
or 
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
or
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d.%m.%Y'))
```

leads to the mentioned error. The conversion happens only if errors='coerce' is added giving the expected result:

```
          Date     DateCP   Time    kWh                  DT
0   01.11.2022 2022-11-01  01:00  0.693 2022-11-01 01:00:00
1   01.11.2022 2022-11-01  02:00  0.675 2022-11-01 02:00:00
2   01.11.2022 2022-11-01  03:00  1.044 2022-11-01 03:00:00
```

Why the coercion is required?

Answer (score 0):

Because wrong data. Here is mixed datetimes with number `0`, so if add `errors='coerce'` parameter pandas convert column to datetimes with `NaT` for not parseable dates.

You can check it:

```
print (df)
         Date      DateCP   Time    kWh                DT
0  01.11.2022  01.11.2022  01:00  0.693  01.11.2022 01:00
1  01.11.2022           1  02:00  0.675  01.11.2022 02:00
2  01.11.2022  01.11.2022  03:00  1.044  01.11.2022 03:00

df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCP'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')

print (df.loc[df['new'].isna(), ['DateCP','new']])

  DateCP new
1      1 NaT
```

So finally DataFrames looks:

```
df['DateCP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCP'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')
print (df)

         Date     DateCP   Time    kWh                DT
0  01.11.2022 2022-11-01  01:00  0.693  01.11.2022 01:00
1  01.11.2022        NaT  02:00  0.675  01.11.2022 02:00
2  01.11.2022 2022-11-01  03:00  1.044  01.11.2022 03:00

print (df.dtypes)
Date              object
DateCP    datetime64[ns]
Time              object
kWh              float64
DT                object
dtype: object
```

EDIT: If need remove all rows with misisng values use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['DateCP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCP'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['DateCP','Date','DT'])
```

Comment: I am beginner, but I do not agree with you - with "coerce" I do not get any cell with NaT , only correct representation (as the examples show), w/o coerce - just error, not NaT. All examples above are prepared by print (df)

Comment: @JanisE - added `EDIT` to answer.